# Compact stream expression for transposing double[][] Matrix

Tags: java, math, java-8, java-stream

I want to tranpose a `double[][]` matrix with the most compact and efficient expression possible.  Right now I have this:

```
public static Function<double[][], double[][]> transpose() {
    return (m) -> {
        final int rows = m.length;
        final int columns = m[0].length;
        double[][] transpose = new double[columns][rows];
        range(0, rows).forEach(r -> {
            range(0, columns).forEach(c -> {
                transpose[c][r] = m[r][c];
            });
        });
        return transpose;
    };
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't see an actual question...

Comment: I think he wants to know whether his way is the most efficient or not and in the second case what is more efficient. But unfortunatly I cannot help with this :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have:

```
public static UnaryOperator<double[][]> transpose() {
    return m -> {
        return range(0, m[0].length).mapToObj(r ->
            range(0, m.length).mapToDouble(c -> m[c][r]).toArray()
        ).toArray(double[][]::new);
    };
}
```

This code does not use `forEach` but prefers `mapToObj` and `mapToDouble` for mapping each row to their transposition. I also changed `Function<double[][], double[][]>` to `UnaryOperator<double[][]>` since the return type is the same.

However, it probably won't be more efficient that having a simple for loop like in [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias)'s answer.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] m = { { 2, 3 }, { 1, 2 }, { -1, 1 } };
    double[][] tm = transpose().apply(m);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tm)); // prints [[2.0, 1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
}
```

---

I've realized a JMH benchmark comparing the code above, the for loop version, and the code above ran in parallel. All three methods are called with random square matrices having size 100, 1000 and 3000. The results are that for small matrices, the `for` loop version is faster but with bigger matrices the parallel Stream solution is indeed better in terms of performance (*Windows 10, JDK 1.8.0_66, i5-3230M @ 2.60 GHz*):

```
Benchmark                           (matrixSize)  Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose                  100  avgt   30    0,026 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose                 1000  avgt   30   14,653 ±  0,205  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose                 3000  avgt   30  222,212 ± 11,449  ms/op
StreamTest.parallelStreamTranspose           100  avgt   30    0,113 ±  0,007  ms/op
StreamTest.parallelStreamTranspose          1000  avgt   30    7,960 ±  0,207  ms/op
StreamTest.parallelStreamTranspose          3000  avgt   30  122,587 ±  7,100  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose                   100  avgt   30    0,040 ±  0,003  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose                  1000  avgt   30   14,059 ±  0,444  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose                  3000  avgt   30  216,741 ±  5,738  ms/op
```

Benchmark code:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(3)
public class StreamTest {

    private static final UnaryOperator<double[][]> streamTranspose() {
        return m -> {
            return range(0, m[0].length).mapToObj(r ->
                range(0, m.length).mapToDouble(c -> m[c][r]).toArray()
            ).toArray(double[][]::new);
        };
    }

    private static final UnaryOperator<double[][]> parallelStreamTranspose() {
        return m -> {
            return range(0, m[0].length).parallel().mapToObj(r ->
                range(0, m.length).parallel().mapToDouble(c -> m[c][r]).toArray()
            ).toArray(double[][]::new);
        };
    }

    private static final Function<double[][], double[][]> forLoopTranspose() {
        return m -> {
            final int rows = m.length;
            final int columns = m[0].length;
            double[][] transpose = new double[columns][rows];
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
                  for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
                    transpose[c][r] = m[r][c];
            return transpose;
        };
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class MatrixContainer {

        @Param({ "100", "1000", "3000" })
        private int matrixSize;

        private double[][] matrix;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setUp() {
            ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            matrix = random.doubles(matrixSize).mapToObj(i -> random.doubles(matrixSize).toArray()).toArray(double[][]::new);
        }

    }

    @Benchmark
    public double[][] streamTranspose(MatrixContainer c) {
        return streamTranspose().apply(c.matrix);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public double[][] parallelStreamTranspose(MatrixContainer c) {
        return parallelStreamTranspose().apply(c.matrix);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public double[][] forLoopTranspose(MatrixContainer c) {
        return forLoopTranspose().apply(c.matrix);
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the matrix was represented as `double[]`, in case of which we wouldn't need to jump around on the heap so much...

Comment: @Tunaki great answer as always!  Could you run it in parallel to see whether there is any performance difference.  If is significantly faster it will really help my presentation to Apache Commons Math.  Lukas you might be interested in the design of CM BlockRealMatrix.  It breaks a large matrix in to small CPU cacheable pieces.

Comment: @user1684269 I made an edit comparing with a parallel solution and it seems it provides better performance starting from 1000x1000 matrices.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks @Tunaki.

Comment: Interesting that tranpose is quite fast given the result we had with matrix multiplication.  I also get good result for large matrices (FM - FireflyMath, CM - Commons Math)  Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
MultiplyBenchmark.transposeCM  avgt   20  1365.956 ± 694.162  ms/op
MultiplyBenchmark.transposeFM  avgt   20  1073.246 ± 241.560  ms/op

Comment: Since tranposing is a copy only operation I figured that it would represent a minimum efficiency gain when compared with operations that also do computation.

Answer (score 3):

As compact and more efficient:

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
  for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    transpose[c][r] = m[r][c];
```

Note that if you have a `Matrix` class that holds a `double[][]`, an alternative option would be to return a view that has the same underlying array but swaps the columns/rows indices. You would save on copying but you may get worse performance on iteration due to worse cache locality.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake [in my benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34861754/1743880) but actually, it seems the performance are the same that with a for loop.

Comment: The mistake is to use a two-dimensional array rather than something like `class Matrix { int width; double[] data; }`

Comment: @LukasEder agreed on performance but wouldn't be as compact ;-)

Comment: @assylias: Meh. You're confusing compact with readable :) `for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)transpose[i*rows+j]=m[j*cols+i];`

Comment: @all this is an attempt to create a new linear algebra module for Apache Commons Math (Also attempting to persuade them to go modular for JDK 9).  CM uses a block matrix (BlockRealMatrix) for faster memory access when the matrix is large.  When it is small, double[][] is used.  Hence the double[][] requirement.  I also have a built in parallel switch in the API for all Function instances, thus I have to use streams in order to keep the API symmetrical.  Thanks for all the great answers so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume a rectangular input (as your original code seems to rely on), you could write it as

```
public static Function<double[][], double[][]> transpose() {
    return m -> range(0, m[0].length)
        .mapToObj(c->range(0, m.length).mapToDouble(r->m[r][c]).toArray())
        .toArray(double[][]::new);
}
```

This could run in parallel but I suppose you’d need a damn big matrix to get a benefit of it.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake [in my benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34861754/1743880) but actually, it seems the performance are the same that with a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

My advice: for simple low-level math you should use plain old for loops instead of Stream API. Also you should benchmark such code very carefully.

As for @Tunaki benchmark. First, you should not limit single measurement with 1 microsecond. The results for `matrixSize = 100` are complete junk: `0,093 ±  0,054` and `0,237 ±  0,134`: the error is more than 50%. Note that time measurement which performed before and after each iteration is not a magic and takes time too. And such a small interval can be easily spoiled by some Windows service which suddenly woke up, took some CPU cycles to check something, then go to sleep again. I usually set every warmup/measurement time to 500ms, this number looks comfortable for me.

Second, when testing Stream API with very simple payload (such as copying numbers to primitive array), you should always test with type profile pollution as it really matters. In clean benchmark the JIT compiler can inline everything into single method, because it knows, for example, that after some `range` you always call the same `mapToObj` with the same lambda expression. But in real application it's not the same. I modified the `MatrixContainer` class this way:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public static class MatrixContainer {
    @Param({"true", "false"})
    private boolean pollute;

    @Param({ "100", "1000", "3000" })
    private int matrixSize;

    private double[][] matrix;

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setUp() {
        ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        matrix = random.doubles(matrixSize)
                       .mapToObj(i -> random.doubles(matrixSize).toArray())
                       .toArray(double[][]::new);
        if(!pollute) return;
        // do some seemingly harmless operations which will
        // poison JIT compiler type profile with some other lambdas
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
           range(0, 1000).map(x -> x+2).toArray();
           range(0, 1000).map(x -> x+5).toArray();
           range(0, 1000).mapToObj(x -> x*2).toArray();
           range(0, 1000).mapToObj(x -> x*3).toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I set 5 forks as for Stream API JIT-compiler may behave differently from run to run. Compilation goes in background thread and profiling info may differ at the compilation point due to race which may change the results of compilation significatly. So within fork the results will be the same, but between forks they might be completely different.

My results are (Windows 7, Oracle JVM 8u45 64bit, some not-very-new i5-2410 laptop):

```
Benchmark                    (matrixSize)  (pollute)  Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose           100       true  avgt   50    0,033 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose           100      false  avgt   50    0,032 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose          1000       true  avgt   50   17,094 ±  0,060  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose          1000      false  avgt   50   17,065 ±  0,080  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose          3000       true  avgt   50  260,173 ±  7,855  ms/op
StreamTest.forLoopTranspose          3000      false  avgt   50  258,774 ±  7,557  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose            100       true  avgt   50    0,096 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose            100      false  avgt   50    0,055 ±  0,012  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose           1000       true  avgt   50   21,497 ±  0,439  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose           1000      false  avgt   50   15,883 ±  0,265  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose           3000       true  avgt   50  272,806 ±  8,534  ms/op
StreamTest.streamTranspose           3000      false  avgt   50  260,515 ±  9,159  ms/op
```

Now you have much less errors and see that type pollution makes the stream results worse while does not affect for-loop results. For matrices like 100x100 the difference is quite significant.

Comment: Hi Tagir -  I appreciate your advice WRT choice of loop construct and your input on the benchmarking analysis.  I need to read up on type pollution some more so that I can better comprehend it.  One of the reasons I've chosen to attempt a pure stream implementation (With great help from all the people here) is in order to make it simple to experiment with concurrency.  I also think the stream constructs are more elegant in general, so hopefully the JIT compiler gets better at optimizing them over time.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The error is indeed much lower with longer warmup time, I'll keep that in mind. Looks like I also need to read up on type pollution :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an implementation example that includes the parallel switch.  I'm curious what you all think of it.

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link UnaryOperator} that transposes the matrix.
 * 
 * Example {@code transpose(true).apply(m);}
 * 
 * @param parallel
 *            Whether to perform the transpose concurrently.
 */
public static UnaryOperator<ArrayMatrix> transpose(boolean parallel) {
    return (m) -> {
        double[][] data = m.getData();
        IntStream stream = range(0, m.getColumnDimension());
        stream = parallel ? stream.parallel() : stream;

        double[][] transpose =
                stream.mapToObj(
                        column -> range(0, data.length).mapToDouble(row -> data[row][column]).toArray())
                        .toArray(double[][]::new);
        return new ArrayMatrix(transpose);
    };
}
```