# More compact identity matrix lambda expression

Tags: java, math, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following expression for creating an identity matrix `double[][]`:

```
public double[][] toArray() {
    double[][] identity = new double[rowDimension][columnDimension];
    range(0, rowDimension).forEach(i -> identity[i][i] = 1);
    return identity;
};
```

I was wondering if that can be compact into a one liner while being equally or more efficient?

Comment: I hope this question is only academical. The currently accepted answer is neither more compact, IMHO far harder to understand, and ... I'm pretty sure that it is far less efficient.

Comment: @Marco13 It isn't less efficient, in fact it is even slightly faster for bigger matrices (and comparable otherwise). I edited my answer with a benchmark showing this.

Comment: If you generate an identity matrix, you should ensure that `rowDimension == columnDimension` or just provide a single dimension since it's a square matrix by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code has a problem when the row count and the column count is not the same (the case of a non-square matrix). You loop over the rows but if there are more rows than columns, the array index will be out of bounds.

Instead of using `forEach`, you can create a Stream pipeline that produces the result you want. In this case, what we need is to map each row into a double array and set the value for the current row index to 1. The rest of the elements will be set to 0, because it is the default value for the `double` primitive.

This would be a sample code:

```
public double[][] toArray() {
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(rowDimension, columnDimension)).mapToObj(r -> {
        double[] row = new double[columnDimension];
        row[r] = 1;
        return row;
    }).toArray(double[][]::new);
}
```

Example of output for `rowDimension = 3` and `columnDimension = 2`:

```
[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
```

---

This is a JMH benchmark comparing the solution above, the code in OP's question and the `for` loop equivalent. The three methods were ran on square matrices with size of 100, 1000 and 3000. Results of benchmark, showing that the above snippet is slightly faster than the other options (*Windows 10, JDK 1.8.0_66, i5-3230M @ 2.60 GHz*):

```
Benchmark                        (length)  Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
StreamTest.toArrayForLoop             100  avgt   50   0,014 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayForLoop            1000  avgt   50   1,348 ±  0,028  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayForLoop            3000  avgt   50  13,588 ±  0,316  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayStream              100  avgt   50   0,015 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayStream             1000  avgt   50   0,788 ±  0,054  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayStream             3000  avgt   50   8,168 ±  0,459  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayStreamForEach       100  avgt   50   0,014 ±  0,001  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayStreamForEach      1000  avgt   50   1,352 ±  0,057  ms/op
StreamTest.toArrayStreamForEach      3000  avgt   50  13,584 ±  0,258  ms/op
```

Code:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 700, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 700, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(5)
public class StreamTest {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class LengthContainer {

        @Param({ "100", "1000", "3000" })
        private int length;

    }

    private static double[][] toArrayStream(int rowDimension, int columnDimension) {
        return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(rowDimension, columnDimension)).mapToObj(r -> {
            double[] row = new double[columnDimension];
            row[r] = 1;
            return row;
        }).toArray(double[][]::new);
    }

    private static double[][] toArrayStreamForEach(int row, int column) {
        double[][] identity = new double[row][column];
        IntStream.range(0, row).forEach(i -> identity[i][i] = 1);
        return identity;
    }

    private static double[][] toArrayForLoop(int row, int column) {
        double[][] matrix = new double[row][column];
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(row, column); i++) {
            matrix[i][i] = 1;
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public double[][] toArrayStream(LengthContainer container) {
        return toArrayStream(container.length, container.length);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public double[][] toArrayForLoop(LengthContainer container) {
        return toArrayForLoop(container.length, container.length);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public double[][] toArrayStreamForEach(LengthContainer container) {
        return toArrayStreamForEach(container.length, container.length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks Tunaki!  It's part of an IdentityMatrix implementation so the rowDimension is always equal to the columnDimension.

Comment: While this might work and be comparable performance, I honestly find the code in the OP's question is much simpler - a new developer could easily understand that code and its intent in seconds. Simplicity has more value than shrinking the lines of code.

Comment: @Chris For a new developer, the whole Stream API is probably hard simply because they're more used to imperative programming (and so relying a lot more than they should on `forEach`). But the Stream API gives the tool to write functional code and you'll find that, written this way, it can be parallelized easily.

Comment: The for loop being slower than the steam is a bit surprising - almost suspicious..

Comment: @assylias Agree, it's surprising. I ran it another time taking into account type pollution ([that I discovered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34868049/1743880)) and the results were the same.

Comment: @assylias Agreed, that is totally unexpected. I don't see a flaw with the JMH benchmark, but did a "manual" one (using the usual mircobenchmarking patterns), and the results are quite different (although I'm currently at an "old/slow" machine, I'll have to check this on a newer one). Could using the `-server` flag bring different results here? On the one hand, I'm hesitant to argue with a JMH result, but this is **so** counterintuitive that I'm also hesitant to simply accept it... Maybe I'll also have a look at the JITed code, to see what it actually does there (if it is not too complicated)

Comment: This result isn’t that surprising if you consider the real difference. It has nothing to do with stream API or for loop. In two cases, a two dimensional array is created and dereferenced afterwards to write the `1` values. In the other, faster case, one dimensional arrays are created and written into before they are assembled to a two dimensional array. You can do the same with a loop, e.g. `double[][] matrix=new double[row][];for(int i=0; i<row; i++){double[]line=new double[column];line[i]=1; matrix[i]=line;}` and it will be on par with the `toArrayStream` variant.