# How to compare a bi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I have this bi-dimensional array:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][]  {
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, 
        { 4, 3, 4, 3, 4},
        { 4, 3, 4, 3, 4},
        { 4, 3, 4, 3, 3},
        { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3},
        { 4, 4, 4, 3, 3},
        { 4, 5, 4, 3, 3},
        { 4, 4, 4, 3, 3}};
```

First I want to compare the first element with the second, then the second with the third and so on, row by row.

Then I want to do the same thing on a column by column basis, comparing the element [0,0] with the element [1,0], then comparing [1,0] with [2,0] and so on, for each column.

That is an easy thing to be done using for() loops:

```
for (int r=0; r<A.length;r++) {
    for (int c=0; c<A[r].length;c++){
        if (if (matrix[r][c]==matrix[r][c+1])){
            // do somet
        }
    }
}
```

But what I need is to do the same using Java 8 functional programming with lambdas and streams iteration.

Comment: I edited your question, but I didn't want to change any code, please edit the `r&lt` and `c&lt` by yourself

Comment: *"But what I need is to do the same using Java 8 functional programming with lambdas and streams iteration."* Great - so what's stopping you? What's your question? Did you try anything?

Comment: what is this: `r&lt`

Comment: Why do you need to use streams?

Comment: Streams are for processing a series of elements independently. It is not for comparing elements that may occur is various *positions* of the stream. A stream is the wrong tool for the job. You can do your code using functional programming, if that is what you desire, but functional programming does not require the use of streams.

Comment: java 8's final release eventually removed the zip function, which would have allowed combining two equal length streams, without that, you would be forced into using `.foreach` instead of a traditional for loop, however in this case, its easier to do it the traditional way, and faster

Comment: @Austin_Anderson FWIW, Guava has a zip function.

Comment: As this solution will require two for() loops iteration similar to the one I shared here, it would be considered too complex, and it's been saying that with java 8 it could be done within one iteration and without for() loops by using functional programming, I don't have that knowledge to build it, so I am asking for help.

Comment: @Wilson Possible? Yes. For example, you can write your own spliterator that yeilds a custom AdjacentPairInfo object, where you access the row numbers, column numbers, and values. Less complex? Heck no.

Comment: I think StreamEx has some utilities for adjacent comparison.

Comment: Could you please fix your code example with the loops. What is A? What is `if (if())` construct?

Comment: Why do you need “*to do the same using Java 8 functional programming with lambdas and streams iteration*”?

Answer (score 2):

You question is a bit unclear to provide universally applicable code. But probably has enough to set you on the right path.

Let's assume you just wanted to find adjacent duplicates:

```
    //reference code
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        for (int c = 0; c < row.length - 1; c++) {
            if (row[c] == row[c + 1]) {
                System.out.print(row[c]+" ");
            }
        }
    }
    //prints 4 4 4 4 3 1 1 3 4 4 3 3 4 4 3
```

Let's also assume your matrix will never contain `-1`. Then you could do

```
    //simple accumulator with a side effect of print out
    IntBinaryOperator accumulator = (acc, x) -> {
        if (acc == x) System.out.print(x + " ");
        return x;
    };

    //also prints 4 4 4 4 3 1 1 3 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 
    Arrays.stream(matrix).forEach(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(-1, accumulator));
```

`reduce(-1, accumulator)` would work on any int array to find same numbers next to each other. Accumulator function keeps previous number in acc and compares with incoming one. Of course, identity as `-1` is cheating, canonical way would be to use `Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()...` and use `null` as identity (and it still would be cheating, but will allow all ints in your matrix).

Here is another version:

```
//prints 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 1 1 3 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 
Arrays.stream(matrix).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).reduce(-1, accumulator);
```

This time no forEach(), but since it flattens the matrix, it will compare last element of a row with first element of the next row - could be a bug or a feature.

Finally, accumulator with a side effect of printing stuff is no good in functional programming. Ideally you should `collect()` a list of duplicates and return it - since your question is so vague, I will trust you can write it yourself with the information above.

You could so some other interesting things with matrices and streams and duplicates, e.g. this will take much more coding than two embedded loops:

```
 Map<Integer,Long> m = Arrays.stream(matrix)
            .parallel()
            .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
 System.out.println(m); //prints occurences of each int: {1=3, 3=15, 4=21, 5=1}
```

In the end, streams are no silver bullet, just a nice help from time to time. Some languages have better syntax and more powerful constructs to adapt functional style, but Java is liked for something else.

Comment: My first thought was that this reduction function violates the associativity constraint, but that applies to the side effect only, which reduction functions shouldn’t have in the first place…

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I think the biggest challenge here is to compare for example test if [0,0]==[1,0], [1,0]==[2,0], and so on, without using for loops,

Comment: @Holger, I freely admit it's a hack :) It won't work with parallel streams and probably has too many limitations to be considered for production code. I mostly provided it as an example of the power of folding.

Comment: @Wilson, you can, of course, transpose the matrix and use the same approach. You can transpose it with streams too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861469/compact-stream-expression-for-transposing-double-matrix; but honestly, I agree with other commenters that loops will do a better job here.

Comment: It might also make sense to look into existing libraries for matrix manipulation. I find (just an opinoin!) EJML (https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml) in Java and Breeze (https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart) in Scala have the cleanest, most usable API while still providing reasonable performance.